# What's the arithmetic form of the value $k$ in this graph?

Tags: arithmetic, constants

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m1kaifseq0

in order to get the control points to line up properly, I had to use trial and error to determine the value for this strange constant $k$ at the bottom of my formula sheet. It's approximately $2.299113817$. I have no idea what the arithmetic representation of it is. If anyone can provide some insight to give me some peace of mind, I would greatly appreciate it.

Analytically, $k$ ought to be the value such that $$c+\frac{a\left(c-b\right)}{\ln2}\frac{2^{-\frac{k}{a}}-1}{k} =\frac{c+b}{2}$$

for any arbitrary $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Edit: I've simplified the equation down somewhat to remove the unnecessary constants, and am left with this:

$$\frac{1}{k2^{k}}-\frac{1}{k}=-\frac{\ln2}{2}$$

I'm not sure if this is easier to solve or not

Further edit: according to Wolfram Alpha, the solution is

$$\frac{2+W\left(-\frac{2}{e^{2}}\right)}{\ln2}$$

which is indeed not pretty...

Final edit: I have decided to define the constant like so in my graph:

$$k=\frac{2+\sum_{m=1}^{66}\frac{\left(-m\right)^{m-1}}{m!}\left(-\frac{2}{e^{2}}\right)^{m}}{\ln2}$$

its not pretty, but it is accurate...

Comment: Looks a lot like $\ln 10=2.302585093$

Comment: @lulu close, but not quite... those decimal places are not arbitrary, i found each and every one by trial and error manually

Comment: I didn't study the graph, has this constant got a definition of some sort or did you just read it off of the plot?  If the latter, then I suppose it's possible that some approximations went into the plot.

Comment: i didnt read it off the plot, i manually chose each digit to make the purple points line up with the red line. i tried looking it up but i couldnt find anything...
there are zero approximations in the plot itself, it's just an exponential function. it ought to have an arithmetic definition, i just cant figure out how to derive it...

Comment: Well, can you define it analytically?  I don't think anyone here is going to study the desmos plot.  how exactly is $k$ defined?

Comment: thats what im trying to figure out...

Comment: ill see what i can do

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to have a pleasant solution....

Comment: ...i just checked wolfram alpha, and i'm afraid you may be correct...

Comment: evidently the solution is $\frac{2+W\left(-\frac{2}{e^{2}}\right)}{\ln2}$ according to wolfram alpha

Comment: and considering the $W$ function is involved, it's not a pretty solution...

Comment: Exactly.  And saying that a value is a special value of the $W$ function is essentially the same as saying it satisfies an equation of the form you wrote...though of course numerical computations for $W(x)$ have been well optimized.